# How do i code in SpriteKit Spawning balls from the top that are now appearing from the side?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a simple game for the iPhone in SpriteKit and am trying to spawn balls coming from the top of the screen. However, the balls keep spawning from the side and I don't know how to make them appear from the top....Anyone an idea on how to change this? (see code). Also is this a good way to randomly spawn? Or should I spawn them and let them fall with gravity rules?

```
//ENEMIES

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}

// 1
func spawnEnemy() {
    // 2
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    // 3
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    // 4
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width + enemy.size.width/2,
                             y: frame.size.height * random(min: 0, max: 1))
    // 5
    addChild(enemy)

    enemy.run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: -size.width - enemy.size.width, y: 0.0,
                         duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 1, max: 2))))

}
```

Comment: ... sounds to me like you are making a landscape game in portrait only mode.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that location (0,0) is the bottom left of the screen, with increasing x values going across the screen from left to right and increasing y values going up the screen from bottom to top.

Your spawn point is always

```
(x: frame.size.width + enemy.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height * random(min: 0, max: 1)
```

which is off the right-hand side of the screen, with a random `y` value (i.e. a random height). Your `x` value needs to be random and your `y` value needs to be:

```
(x: frame.size.width * random(min: 0, max: 1), y: frame.size.height + enemy.size.height/2)
```

Then, as Dreamer said, your movement SKAction needs to move the enemy from its current y value to 0 whilst keeping its x value constant (assuming you want it to move straight down the screen.

As to your question about spawning and gravity - do you want your objects to move down at a constant speed (which is what your corrected SKAction will do) or to look as though they are falling under gravity, in which case they'd appear, then start moving slowly but constantly accelerating.

Edit: As KnightOfDragons said - the actual location of the (0, 0) co-ordinate is governed by a property known as the `anchorPoint` (which itself is a CGPoint, but this doesn't relate to an actual co-ordinate). It used to always be (0, 0) which means the bottom left-hand corner, but now it may to be (0.5, 0.5), which means the centre of the screen i.e. a sprite placed at (0,0) will be in the middle of the screen. Increasing x or y will move the sprite right or up respectively, and decreasing x or y will move the sprite left or down.

This means that if your scene has an anchorPoint of (0.5, 0.5), then the edges of the screen will have a co-ordinates of:

- top of screen - y: frame.size.height/2
- bottom of screen - y: -frame.size.height/2
- right-hand edge of screen - x: frame.size.width/2
- left-hand edge of screen - x: -frame.size.height/2

Whether or not the anchorPont is (0, 0) or (0.5, 0.5) may be dependant upon if your scene came from an .sks file or through code.

Comment: New template puts 0,0 at the center now

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - is this only for scenes instantiated via an .sks file, or through code as well? (Not had a chance to test).

Comment: Just the SKS file,  default for the class has anchor point at 0,0 still I think.  Never tested it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
enemy.run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: -size.width - enemy.size.width, y: 0.0,
                         duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 1, max: 2))))
```

You need to be moving by -Y. X is left and right, Y is up and down. So it would be....

```
enemy.run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: 0.0 , y: -size.height - enemy.size.height,
                         duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 1, max: 2))))
```

Comment: This is true for the movement, but he's placing his sprites off the right-hand side of the screen rather than at the top,  so he needs to address their initial placement too.